# ¿Como puedo mostrar un DIV desde otro DIV al cual se le pasa el mouse encima?

Tags: html, jquery, css

estoy creando una página web y necesito que, al momento de pasar el mouse por encima de un DIV, abajo aparesca otro DIV

Comment: Hola Rafael, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio. Esta preguntas es demasiado amplia porque aunque la tarea es **clara** has de explicar qué has intentado y qué problemas concretos has tenido, que son sobre los que te podemos ayudar. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar JQuery

```
$("#ELEMENTO").hover(function(){
$("#ELEMENTO").after("<div></div>");
},function(){});
```

Saludos :)

Comment: Buenas, Rubén. Gracias por aportar. Sin embargo es mejor esperar a que el autor mejore la pregunta mostrando lo que ha investigado e intentado antes de resolverle la tarea. es mejor ayudar con su problema particular que hacerle el trabajo. Un saludo